# Hibernate, не выводится в консоль результат

Tags: java, hibernate

Начал осваивать *Hibernate*. Написал программу, но при запуске результат не выводится в консоль, а только такой лог:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-
Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA           
15.0.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\rt.jar;E:\_work\java\test2LS\target\classes;
C:\Users\emina\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.4.191\h2-1.4.191.jar;
C:\Users\emina\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.1.0.Final\hibernate-core-
5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\emina\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-
logging\3.3.0.Final\jboss-logging-
3.3.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\emina\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hi
bernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-
1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\emina\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.20.0-
GA\javassist-3.20.0-
GA.jar;C:\Users\emina\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-
2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\emina\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-
jta_1.1_spec\1.1.1\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-
1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\emina\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.0.Final\jandex-
2.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\emina\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.0\clas
smate-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\emina\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-
1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\emina\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-
1.0.b2.jar;C:\Users\emina\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-
commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-
5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 
15.0.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Main
апр 18, 2016 10:39:46 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
апр 18, 2016 10:39:46 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
апр 18, 2016 10:39:46 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
апр 18, 2016 10:39:47 AM     
org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
апр 18, 2016 10:39:47 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
апр 18, 2016 10:39:47 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:~/test]
апр 18, 2016 10:39:47 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
апр 18, 2016 10:39:47 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
апр 18, 2016 10:39:47 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
апр 18, 2016 10:39:48 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
апр 18, 2016 10:39:49 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:h2:~/test]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

В файле *Main.java* в конце вывод в `foreach`, но ничего не выводит, ни через геттеры, ни через переопределенный `toString()`

Структура проекта следующая:

```
/src
  /main
    /java
      FileStatistic.java  
      HibernateUtil.java  
      LineStatistic.java  
      Main.java  
    /resources
      fileStatistic.cfg.xml
      hibernate.cfg.xml  
      lineStatistic.cfg.xml  
  /test
pom.xml
```

Сам файл *pom.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>aliiev.emin</groupId>
<artifactId>test2LS</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.191</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Файл *hibernate.cfg.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  
<hibernate-configuration>  
    <session-factory>  
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:~/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name = "hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <mapping resource="fileStatistic.cfg.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lineStatistic.cfg.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Файл *fileStatistic.cfg.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="FileStatistic" table="FILE_STATISTIC">
        <id name="idFile" column="ID_FILE">
            <generator class="select"/>
        </id>
        <property name="maxFileWord" column="MAX_FILE_WORD"/>
        <property name="minFileWord" column="MIN_FILE_WORD"/>
        <property name="avgFileWord" column="AVG_FILE_WORD"/>
        <property name="avgFileLineLength" column="AVG_LINE_LENGTH"/>
        <set name="lineStatistics" table="LINESTATISTIC">
            <key>
                <column name="ID_FILE"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="LineStatistic"/>
        </set>
    </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Файл *lineStatistic.cfg.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="LineStatistic" table="LINE_STATISTIC">
        <id name="idLine" column="ID_LINE">
            <generator class="select"/>
        </id>
        <property name="maxWord" column="MAX_WORD"/>
        <property name="minWord" column="MIN_WORD"/>
        <property name="avgWord" column="AVG_WORD"/>
        <property name="lineLength" column="LINE_LENGTH"/>
        <many-to-one name="fileStatistic" class="FileStatistic">
            <column name="ID_FILE"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Файл *HibernateUtil.java*:

```java
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;  
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;  
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;  

public class HibernateUtil {  
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;  

    static {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties());

        sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Файл *Main.java*:

```java
import org.hibernate.Criteria;  
import org.hibernate.Session;  
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;  
import java.util.List;  

public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<FileStatistic> fileStatistic = null;

        try {
            session.beginTransaction();

            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(FileStatistic.class);
            fileStatistic = criteria.list();

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
            sessionFactory.close();
        }

        for (FileStatistic fStatistic:fileStatistic) {
            System.out.println(fStatistic.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проблема решена, переписаны конфиги(заголовки xml-файлов) для маппинга классов, самого хибера, а также переписан SessionFactory.
новый вид файлов имеет следующий вид:

файл `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    ...(эта часть без изменений)
</hibernate-configuration>
```

файл `fileStatistic.cfg.xml:`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="FileStatistic" table="FILE_STATISTIC">
        ...(эта часть без изменений)
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

файл `lineStatistic.cfg.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="LineStatistic" table="LINE_STATISTIC">
        ...(эта часть без изменений)
            <many-to-one name="fileStatistic" class="FileStatistic" insert="false" update="false">// добавлено insert="false" update="false"
            <column name="ID_FILE" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

файл `HibernateUtil.java`:

```java
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    static {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Отлично, еще не забудьте отметить ответ ка верный (галочка под счетчиком голосов).

Comment: спасибо, но, оказывается, мне это можно будет сделать только завтра ))))

Comment: Да, такой таймаут дается на случай, если появится другой хороший ответ.